# How to install another cms in a sub-directory of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to install shopping cart cms "x-cart" in a sub-directory "/store/"  on my Wordpress site.

I have permalinks enabled and mod rewrite in htaccess... So when I try to access anything within "/store/" folder i am getting wordpress 404 :(

How do I exclude "/store/" folder in htaccess?

Here is my current one:

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a folder called "store" you don't need to do anything. This line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Is saying that "If the request is from a real directory (-d) ignore this index.php stuff and go with it". So, just create /store and put a "index.html" to see if it isn't an issue with x-cart instead of wp

Comment: Its weird, it wasn't working yesterday, yet today its all working fine all at the sudden :)

Comment: Oh strange things happen on this internet land ;)

Comment: One more question, does it work the same way with subfolders in the "store" folder? For some reason I am having problems accessing the urls inside subfolders... :(

Comment: It meant to work.. /store/realfolder/ shouldn't redirect since it falls in the rule (folder exists)

Comment: For some reason permissions where messed up, after changing everything is working perfectly.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating multi WP website, you can consider using WP multisites feature which can be found [here<sup>codex</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to either install x-cart on a sub-domain (store.yoursite.com), or just put it in a folder at the same level as wordpress yoursite.com/store.

Comment: Its weird, it wasn't working yesterday, yet today its all working fine all at the sudden :)